# SF Symbols (SwiftUI) Is there a fingerprint symbol for TouchID?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, sf-symbols

I am not sure if SF Symbols ever had a fingerprint, but does anybody know where to get the official Touch ID fingerprint icon for use in an app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through SF Symbols again and may have missed it.  I'm just going to use this for now, unless someone is able to provide an official route.  It has CC attribution 3.0.

[iOS Touch ID Fingerprint Icon](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/363335/finger_print_id_touch_touch_id_icon)

Update (06/25/2020):
SF Symbols 2 seems to have re-added the touchid icon.  You can refer to it by "touchid."

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/

e.g.

```
Image(systemName: "touchid")
```

Comment: Note: it's available in SFSymbols starting with iOS 14+.